# Validate Dynamic Input Fields Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm adding dynamic input fields to a web form. I'm validating these using this [Jquery Mask](https://github.com/igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin) plugin.

It works fine on the initial input, but not the ones added dynamically.

My input HTML is;

```
<input type="text" id="mac_address" name="MacAddress[]">
```

My button HTML is;

```
<button class="add-mac" type="button" title="Add">Add</button>
```

The syntax used to validate the input is (works on first input only);

```
$('#mac_address').mask('ZZ-ZZ-ZZ-ZZ-ZZ-ZZ', {
    translation: {
        'Z': {
            pattern: /[A-Fa-f0-9]/,
            optional: false,
        }
    }
});
```

How can I add this validation to the dynamic inputs?

I have tried adding the code to a `each` loop although it doesn't work.

```
$('.add-mac').click(function() {
    $('#mac_address').each(function() {
        $(this).mask('ZZ-ZZ-ZZ-ZZ-ZZ-ZZ', {
            translation: {
                'Z': {
                    pattern: /[A-Fa-f0-9]/,
                    optional: false,
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: You can't/shouldn't use same id to multiple elements in a single page

Comment: `$('#mac_address').each(function() {` does not make any sense. There can only be *one* DOM element with the ID "mac_address" on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added class to input

```
  <input type="text" class="mac_address" id="mac_address" name="MacAddress[]">
    <button class="add-mac" type="button" title="Add">Add</button>

    <script>
    var count = 1;
    $('.add-mac').click(function() {

     $('.mac_address').last().clone().attr('id', 'mac_address' + count).val('').insertBefore($(this));
    count ++; 
    });
    $(document).on('keyup', '.mac_address', function(){
      $('.mac_address').mask('ZZ-ZZ-ZZ-ZZ-ZZ-ZZ', {
        translation: {
            'Z': {
                pattern: /[A-Fa-f0-9]/,
                optional: false,
            }
        }
    });
    })
      $('.mac_address').mask('ZZ-ZZ-ZZ-ZZ-ZZ-ZZ', {
        translation: {
            'Z': {
                pattern: /[A-Fa-f0-9]/,
                optional: false,
            }
        }
    }); 
</script>
```

https://codepen.io/vommbat/pen/MBXeoj

Answer (score 0):

change the id to class

```
<input type="text" class="mac_address" name="MacAddress[]">
<button class="add-mac" type="button" title="Add">Add</button>

<script>
$('.add-mac').click(function() {
    $('.mac_address').each(function() {
        $(this).mask('ZZ-ZZ-ZZ-ZZ-ZZ-ZZ', {
            translation: {
                'Z': {
                    pattern: /[A-Fa-f0-9]/,
                    optional: false,
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```